# FB login fails after duplicating xcode project to create lite version of app

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, authentication

I created an iPhone app that posts to Facebook, successfully. I then duplicated the app to create a lite version and did the following:

1. I created a new story and action in FB for the post, for which I:

   - Added a new namespace for the lite version
   - entered the bundle identifier for my lite app
   - entered the FB site login URL to point to a new html file which I copied from the full app (and updated the contents of that file to ensure it had the right App ID and namespace)
2. updated my app:

   - changed the FB App ID in my app on the Info page
   - updated the URL Scheme in the URL Types section of the Info page
   - updated all occurrences of the FB namespace from the full app's namespace to the lite app's namespace

...but when I run the app (on a device), it doesn't work and fails with the following:

Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "The operation could not be completed" & "An unknown error occurred"

I've not posted any code as the code itself hasn't changed and works perfectly on the full version.  I'm missing something (probably obvious!). Any pointers greatly received :-)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed something really obvious! In trying to duplicate everything I had done for the full app, I, correctly, added a test user to the Facebook app but I forgot to login to that test user account on Facebook and accept the request!

Hope that helps someone else :-)